# Coldfusion/IIS - Errors occuring when refreshing pages

Tags: iis, coldfusion

We have 2 load balanced web servers running Windows Server 2012 and ColdFusion 11 which replaced servers running Windows Server 2008 and ColdFusion 10. We had no issues under ColdFusion 10. Under ColdFusion 11 pages initially load without error but refreshing the page in the browser consistently produces error messages in Firefox developer tools similar to below.

```
GET http://abc.web.def.com/CFIDE/scripts/cfform.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 98ms]

GET http://abc.web.def.com/CFIDE/scripts/masks.js [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 105ms]

GET http://abc.web.def.com/includes/jquery/UI/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-1.8.3.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 102ms]

GET http://abc.web.def.com/includes/jquery/UI/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 105ms]

GET http://abc.web.def.com/myFolder/mySubFolder/myApp.css [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 105ms]
```

Again, these errors don't occur on initial page load - only when the page is refreshed and as a result it is impossible to get a page to reload completely. The issue occurs on both of the new servers. We've compared every IIS and ColdFusion setting we can think of, to no avail.

Any idea as to what is going on here?

Comment: If the error only occurs on reload, possible causes could be cookies (session-handling) or the http-referrer. As far as I know these are the only parts of a GET request that differ on the second run.

Comment: (Edit) Yes, cookie/session related issues would be my first guess as well. What kind of persistence? Also, what errors do you see in the logs: IIS failed request logs, CF error logs, event logs, etc...?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Any further advise on troubleshooting or verifying session handling? Leigh - what do you mean by persistence? The IIS error log is empty; no CF error are logged on these failures. Still reviewing the event logs but nothing so far...

Comment: Did you search both cf_root\logs and \runtime\logs\? I guess whether they contain any info depends on exactly when the error occurs. Is failed request tracing enabled in IIS (probably not enabled by default)? Is the load balancer using some sort of sticky session or [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29#Persistence)?

Comment: The 304 status code are not errors. The web server should send that on a refresh to tell the browser it is okay to use its cached version (the file has not been modified).  The 500 error on JavaScript and css files is odd.  By persistence we mean is the load balancer configured to deliver each request from the browser to the same ColdFusion server? Otherwise each request may be delivered to a different server than the first and that will cause session errors if they are not shared.

Comment: Also those 500 errors should be writing some entries is the Windows system event log. Look there.  You won't find anything in the ColdFusion logs because those are not files handled by ColdFusion (js and css from your example). And if you don't see any of these requests or errors on your web servers then the response could be coming from your load balancer.

Comment: @Miguel-F - Good catch on the file type. I did not notice they are all css/js files, doh.  user3455390 - Is it *only* those file types?

Comment: I really appreciate the responses. It turns out the culprit was the web.config files under the root folder of the sites (we have 2). I'm not even sure how it happened, but we seemed to have had a mixture of CF10 and CF11 versions of web.config, e.g. Server 1: site A with CF10 version, site B with CF 11 and then Server 2: site A with CF11 and site B with CF10. What's the proper way to close this question out?

Comment: You can just add an answer with your solution. It is okay to answer your own question. Try to be descriptive. That way if someone comes across this issue later they can clearly see what the issue was. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the culprit was the web.config files under the root folder of the sites (we have 2). I'm not even sure how it happened, but we seemed to have had a mixture of CF10 and CF11 versions of web.config, e.g.

Server 1:

- site A with CF10 version
- site B with CF11 version

Server 2:

- site A with CF11 version
- site B with CF10 version

My co-worked actually figured this out after getting an error in IIS manager when attempting to view mime types on one of the sites. IIS manager returned an error pointing to a problem with web.config.

Comment: "This week on the WebDev channel: Web.config files, friend or foe?" ;-)

Comment: I have had my share of headaches dealing with web.config files.